# How to change between fragments with buttons inside the fragments in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, kotlin, fragment

I hope I am not asking a repeated question, but  only found this answer in java and I am using Kotlin. I am trying to exchange between fragments using buttons. Here is my code. First of all, Thanks.

For main

```
       class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity (){
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

And its xml file

```
           <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:name="com.example.stackoverflow.fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For Fragment1

```
      class fragment1 : Fragment(){
       override fun onCreateView(Layoutinflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?, savedInstantState: Bundle?): View? {
        return Layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#faaf45"))
     button1.setOnClickListener(){
           //Not sure what to put here
        }
}
```

And fragment2

```
       class fragment2 : Fragment(){
        override fun onCreateView(Layoutinflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?, savedInstantState: Bundle?): View? {
        return Layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false)
    }
         override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
         button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaf45"))
       button2.setOnClickListener(){
         //Not sure what to put here
        }
}
```

Comment: You should use navigation component if you want to navigate between fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Or you can use FragmentTransactions, which is the same mechanism as what the FragmentNavigator uses in the Navigation component

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity (){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun changeFragment(fragmnet:Fragment){
      getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

In MainActivity laout :

```
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

In fragment1:

```
class fragment1 : Fragment(){
   override fun onCreateView(Layoutinflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?, savedInstantState: Bundle?): View?  {
    return Layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container,false)
    }
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#faaf45"))
    button1.setOnClickListener(){
       (context as MainActivity).changeFragment(fragmnet2.newInstance())
    }
  companion object {
    fun newInstance(): fragment1 {
        return fragment1()
     }
    }
 }
```

In fragment2:

```
class fragment2 : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(Layoutinflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?, savedInstantState: Bundle?): View? {
    return Layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false)
   }
     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
     button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaf45"))
   button2.setOnClickListener(){
     (context as MainActivity).changeFragment(fragmnet1.newInstance())
    }

  companion object {
      fun newInstance(): fragment2 {
        return fragment2()
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, fails. I am using kotlin and this looks like java.

Comment: Changed in kotlin let me know if more help needed.Also you can use this link for more details :https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/how-to-add-a-fragment-in-kotlin-way-73203c5a450b

Comment: this is kotilin ! I just added a simple code. But the solution is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this. It is giving me de error (25, 27): Unresolved reference: container. What can I do?

Comment: You should have FrameLayout in MainActivity by this id -> (R.id.container)

Comment: You should change <fragment> in main layout with <FrameLayout>

Comment: I did the changes (<fragment> by <FrameLayout> and @+id/main by @+id/container) now the error is (25, 38): Unresolved reference: fragment

Comment: I edit the answer and writ complete code. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks for the new answer, but still have troubles:
25, 38): Unresolved reference: fragment (In the main)
(26, 18): Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) (In Fragment1)
(27, 54): Unresolved reference: fragmnet2 (In fragment1)
May be do I need an import to make this work? I am using androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
 class fragment1 : Fragment(){
   override fun onCreateView(Layoutinflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?, savedInstantState: Bundle?): View? {
    return Layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false)
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#faaf45"))
 button1.setOnClickListener(){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment2()).commit()        }
 }
```

And fragment2

```
class fragment2 : Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(Layoutinflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?, savedInstantState: Bundle?): View? {
    return Layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false)
}
     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
     button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaf45"))
   button2.setOnClickListener(){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment1()).commit() 
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can't use `replace()` when you use the `<fragment>` tag

Comment: thanks for the rewriting, I tried that code and this was the result:
(29, 13): Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager
Do I need a specific import?